# DB Error with Solspace Friends on new Install of EE 2.5.5. Solutions?

Tags: security, solspace

I'm testing the code pack from Solspace for the Friends module. This is on a brand new clean install of EE 2.5.5

The error occurs when trying to add a comment. Full error code below

Having done a search it seems that it's an issue on the EE side rather than because of a specific add-on.

Does anybody have a solution that does not involve core hacking?

Thanks.

```
ERROR

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'ip_address' in 'where clause'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM exp_security_hashes WHERE hash = '9633427c80112996dc4a9da76c64abca2a2482fc' AND ip_address = 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX' AND date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-7200

Filename: third_party/friends/mod.friends.php

Line Number: 8383
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening as the `ip_address` column was dropped in EE 2.5.4 and replaced with column `session_id`

Solspace 'Friends' hasn't been updated since September 20th 2012 so it hasn't been patched to fix this issue. The only way around this is to either wait for an update or 'hack' mod.friends.php

There will be a **pre xid check** in the comments of this file - this section needs to be updated to work with EE 2.5.4+,

You'll need to use **ee()->security->check_xid(ee()**

If you have any other solspace modules that have been updated (User / Freeform) you should be able to patch it together.

Comment: Thanks, Jamie. Solspace are on the case so I would hope that an update is coming soon. I'd rather wait a few days than get into the horror of hacking modules.

Comment: Dropping of `ip_address` has also broken Safecracker Registration.

Answer (score 1):

Got a repsonse from Solspace Support. It's an issue that affects many add-ons and it seems that it's the add-on developers responsibility to modify their code.

http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/15096/